# Calculating dates differences from to Strings in TextFields

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, textfield

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two dates picked with Date Picker in two Text Fields and display the result in UILabel.

The firs part with popup date picker and date format is working fine but when I try to calculate the dates (code was tested and working in Play Ground) the Xcode generate plenty of errors. I think this is showing how little understanding I have for swift and I'm pretty sure that the errors are because some fundamental mistake, which I not able to catch.

Any advise will be highly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var startDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var endDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var workingDays: UILabel!


    // Start Date Text Field- action and format for DatePicker
    @IBAction func startDateTextFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {
        var datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("startDatePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    func startDatePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        var dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        startDate.text = dateformatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
        println("Start Date is " + startDate.text)
    }

    // End Date Text Field - action and format for DatePicker
    @IBAction func endDateTextFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {
        var datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("endDatePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    func endDatePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        var dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        endDate.text = dateformatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
        println("End Date is " + endDate.text)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    // Convert the String to NSDate
    var start = startDate.Text
    var end = endDate.text
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    let startDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start)!
    let endDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(end)!

    // Diference between two NSDate -> Int +1
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let unit: NSCalendarUnit = .DayCalendarUnit
    let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: nil )
    let calulatedDays = components.day + 1

    // Set String for UILabel workingDays
    workingDays.text = "\(calculatedDays)"
    println(workingDays)

}
```

Comment: "generating plenty of errors" is too vague. Debugging code from a forum post is painful at best, impossible at worst.  If it won't compile, list the errors you can't figure out. If you aren't getting the results you want, tell us what's going wrong.

Comment: You are right. Please accept my apology.

Comment: Why would you need to convert string back to date considering that you can just get the date from the date picker

Answer (score 1):

The first mistake I'm doing is that I want to take the value of the TextField as a String and to sign it to a variable.
The error message generated from this is

> 'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'inputTaxtField'

One more time, please excuse my for the long code above.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!

    var myString = inputTextField.text

}
```

Comment: Probably have to include the var in a func and take into account that the field is empty in the beginning, so will return nil.

Comment: Don't use answers to expand your question. Edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You show 3 outlets in your original post, but none of them have the name `inputTaxtField`. In your additional post you show `inputTextField`. Different spelling. Either of those things could be the cause of your problem

Comment: Thank you Duncan. I have just simplify the query with one outlet UITextField and attempt to create the var String from the content of the Text Field.